# how can i get my category name when value type is id in dropdown flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart, flutter-dropdownbutton

i am trying to show category name and store category id in database but my categories id are not line by line

My Dropdown button

```
                      DropdownButton(
                        items: categoriesList.map((item) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem(
                              child: Text(item['name'].toString()), value: item['id'].toString());
                        }).toList(),
                        onChanged: (changedCategoryId) {
                          setState(() {
                            print(int.parse(changedCategoryId.toString()));
                          });
                        },
                        hint: Text(selectedCategory),
                      ),
```

fetch data code

```
  List categoriesList = [];
  var selectedCategory = "Select Category";

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    fetchCategories();
    super.initState();
  }

  fetchCategories() async {
    var fetchedCategoriesList =
        await http.get(Uri.parse("${AppConfig.BASE_URL}categories"));
    var decodedFetchedCategoriesList =
        json.decode(fetchedCategoriesList.body)['data'];
    setState(() {
      categoriesList = decodedFetchedCategoriesList;
    });
    print(categoriesList);
  }
```

Comment: what do you mean line by line?

Comment: like my id is not 1,2,3 its like 4,6,16 etc

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of your output?

Answer (score 0):

```
onChanged: (changedCategoryId) { // this runType is Dropdow
     final id  = changedCategoryId['id'];
     final name = changedCategoryId['name'];
},
```

you can store the id to database , and show the name on screen